# Firefox does not display text after the installation of new fonts

Tags: firefox, fonts

Ubuntu 14.04, after install new fonts, when enter a page, Firefox just display images, it does not display text.

I tried to `chown` the folder `/usr/share/fonts' to my user and`chmod`the folder`/usr/share/fonts`to`777` but it still does not display text.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given elsewhere in the site as follows:
Go to browser settings as in edit>preferences>content>advanced and uncheck the box that allows other programs to choose the fonts for the page and use the fonts that I choose.

But I found that this does not work for all languages. Some Indian languages are still not displayed, for instance.